# Error 1054: Unknown Column in Where Clause

Tags: mysql

I just started working with MySQL last week, and I'm attempting to write a code to check for the earliest instance of a billing record for a certain address and mark it as "NEW". It should also identify if an account has since been cancelled and mark the first instance of a cancelled record as "NEW". The code compiles, but whenever I try to test it by inputting an address, I receive "Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'BillingRecords.Address' in 'where clause'" I feel like I've tried every fix for the column references under the sun (with/without backticks, single quotes, database names, table names, etc.) How exactly should I be referencing the columns in the code to avoid this error? Also, since I haven't been able to test it properly, there may be a few other errors in the code. If you notice anything, I'd really appreciate some feedback.

## Code in question

```
SELECT Min(`Date`) INTO earliestDate FROM Billing.BillingRecords WHERE `Address` = addressToCheck; #Determines the earliest date of all instances of the specified address
SELECT Min(`Date`) INTO earliestCancelDate FROM Billing.BillingRecords WHERE `Address` = addressToCheck AND `Cancel` = "Cancelled"; #Determines the earliest date of all instances of the specified address where the account has been marked as "Cancelled"

CASE
    WHEN `BillingRecords`.`Address` = addressToCheck AND `BillingRecords`.`Date` = earliestDate THEN
        SET isItNew = "NEW"; #Returns "NEW" if the address matches the specified address and the date matches the earliest date
    WHEN `BillingRecords`.`Address` = addressToCheck AND `BillingRecords`.`Date` != earliestDate THEN
        SET isItNew = "OLD"; #Returns "OLD" if the address matches the specified address and the date does not match the earliest date
    ELSE
        SET isItNew = NULL;
END CASE;


CASE    
    WHEN `BillingRecords`.`Address` = addressToCheck AND `BillingRecords`.`Date` = earliestCancelDate AND `BillingRecords`.`Cancel` = "Cancelled" THEN
        SET isItNewCancel = "NEW"; #Returns "NEW" if the address matches the specified address, the account is marked as "Cancelled", and the date matches the earliest cancel date
    WHEN `BillingRecords`.`Address` = addressToCheck AND `BillingRecords`.`Date` != earliestCancelDate AND `BillingRecords`.`Cancel` = "Cancelled" THEN
        SET isItNewCancel = "OLD"; #Returns "OLD" if the address matches the specified address, the account is marked as "Cancelled", and the date does not match the earliest date
    ELSE
        SET isItNewCancel = NULL;
END CASE;
```

Comment: can you put the output of `DESC Billing.BillingRecords;`?

Comment: (most common reason for this error is you are mispelling the identifier or missing an alias reference, but you are not using aliases so that leaves only the first possibility. Or the table does not in fact have an address column...)

Comment: really hard to tell, but have you tried `WHERE \`BillingRecords\`.\`Address\`` in your first 2 lines?

Comment: Here's just the columns in question (it's a large table):

Address varchar(145) YES MUL NULL
Cancel varchar(45) YES  NULL
Date         date                 YES  NULL

Comment: @Matt HB- I have, but it just winds up giving me Error 1109: Unknown table "BillingRecords" in field list