# Multiple Errors for Not Finding Columns and Tables in Database

Tags: mysql

I just started working with MySQL last week, and I'm attempting to write a code to check for the earliest instance of a billing record for a certain address and mark it as "NEW". It should also identify if an account has since been cancelled and mark the first instance of a cancelled record as "NEW". The code compiles, but whenever I try to test it by inputting an address, I receive "Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'BillingRecords.Address' in 'where clause'" I feel like I've tried every fix for the column references under the sun (with/without backticks, single quotes, database names, table names, etc.) How exactly should I be referencing the columns in the code to avoid this error? Also, since I haven't been able to test it properly, there may be a few other errors in the code. If you notice anything, I'd really appreciate some feedback.

The columns I am using are:
Address varchar(145)    YES MUL NULL
Cancel varchar(45)      YES     NULL
Date   date             YES     NULL

I hope it's alright to repost this question. I have yet to get the code working. Original thread [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31186758/error-1054-unknown-column-in-where-clause)

## Code in Question

```
SELECT Min(`Date`) INTO earliestDate FROM Billing.BillingRecords WHERE `Address` = addressToCheck; #Determines the earliest date of all instances of the specified address
SELECT Min(`Date`) INTO earliestCancelDate FROM Billing.BillingRecords WHERE `Address` = addressToCheck AND `Cancel` = "Cancelled"; #Determines the earliest date of all instances of the specified address where the account has been marked as "Cancelled"

CASE
    WHEN `BillingRecords`.`Address` = addressToCheck AND `BillingRecords`.`Date` = earliestDate THEN
        SET isItNew = "NEW"; #Returns "NEW" if the address matches the specified address and the date matches the earliest date
    WHEN `BillingRecords`.`Address` = addressToCheck AND `BillingRecords`.`Date` != earliestDate THEN
        SET isItNew = "OLD"; #Returns "OLD" if the address matches the specified address and the date does not match the earliest date
    ELSE
        SET isItNew = NULL;
END CASE;


CASE    
    WHEN `BillingRecords`.`Address` = addressToCheck AND `BillingRecords`.`Date` = earliestCancelDate AND `BillingRecords`.`Cancel` = "Cancelled" THEN
        SET isItNewCancel = "NEW"; #Returns "NEW" if the address matches the specified address, the account is marked as "Cancelled", and the date matches the earliest cancel date
    WHEN `BillingRecords`.`Address` = addressToCheck AND `BillingRecords`.`Date` != earliestCancelDate AND `BillingRecords`.`Cancel` = "Cancelled" THEN
        SET isItNewCancel = "OLD"; #Returns "OLD" if the address matches the specified address, the account is marked as "Cancelled", and the date does not match the earliest date
    ELSE
        SET isItNewCancel = NULL;
END CASE;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error 1054: Unknown Column in Where Clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31186758/error-1054-unknown-column-in-where-clause)

Comment: I mentioned in the body that I was reposting the question. Is that acceptable here? I'm a Stack newbie.

Comment: Sorry, reposting is concidered [duplication](http://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates). Please either edit the original or [ask a more focused question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).